# Tensorflow model not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm just starting learning ML/Tensorflow/etc, so I'm pretty novice and still don't really know what the troubleshooting method is like. I'm currently having an issue with my model as it doesn't seem to really ever improve. For instance, the output appears as

```
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 41s 10s/step - loss: 0.8833 - accuracy: 0.4300
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 12s 3s/step - loss: 0.8833 - accuracy: 0.4300
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 10s 3s/step - loss: 0.8833 - accuracy: 0.4300
Epoch 7/1000
4/4 [==============================] - 10s 3s/step - loss: 0.8833 - accuracy: 0.4300
```

The main aspect that worries me is that it doesn't change at all which makes me think I'm doing something completely wrong. To give some more context and code, I am trying to do some time series classification. Basically, the input is the normalized time series of the song and the net should classify if it's classical music (output of 1 means it is, output of 0 means it isn't).

This is the current model I am trying.

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=10000,  strides=5000, input_shape=(1323000, 1), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=10, strides=3, input_shape=(263, 100), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.LSTM(1000),
    keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is how I get the training data (x and y are dictionaries with time series from different songs).

```
minute = 1323000
x_train = np.zeros((100, minute, 1))
y_train = np.zeros((100,))
for kk in range(0, 100):
    num = randint(0, 41)
    ts = x[num]
    start = randint(0, len(ts) - minute)
    x_train[kk, :] = np.array([ts[start:(start + minute)]]).T
    y_train[kk] = 1 - y[num]
```

and then training:

```
for kk in range(1, 1000):
    x_train, y_train = create_training_set(x, y)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

I looked at some similar questions asked, however, I was already doing what was suggested or the advice was too specific for the asker. I also tried some relatively different models/activators, so I don't think it's because the model is too complicated and the data is already normalized, so that shouldn't be an issue. But, as I said, I'm knew to all this and could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `softmax` activation in a single-node last layer is not correct. Additionally, the argument `from_logits=True` in your loss definition means that the model is expected to produce logits, and not probabilities (which are generally produced by `softmax` and `sigmoid` final activations).

So, you should change your last layer to

```
keras.layers.Dense(1) # linear activation by default
```

Alternatively, you could change both your last layer and your loss function respectively to

```
keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
```

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy), usage of `from_logits=True` may be more numerically stable, and probably this is the reason it is preferred in the standard Tensorflow classification tutorials (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)).

Answer (score 1):

So I can't promise this is going to work, because I don't know your data and this is a very weird architecture, but here are a few things that seem wrong:

1. Last dense layer should have `sigmoid` activation function
2. `from_logits` should be `False`

Comment: Well, you beat me for 2 minutes... :)

Comment: It's okay. Your answer is well written and contains elements that I didn't cover.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I will take the weird architecture comment as a compliment :)